# proc means in SAS has variables, says no variables when run

Tags: sas

My code log is below. I do not understand how, after I copy/paste file to my work library where it tells me I have 2225 obs and 39 variables, when I run the proc means for that same file, it says 1 obs, 0 variables.

Is it a code I'm typing incorrectly? Could it be processing power of my Surface Pro3. 
I'm accessing SAS 9.3 through schools app portal. I do not have SAS on my computer.

```
NOTE: The data set WORK.NONCMAAPPENDED has 2225 observations and 39 variables. 

1    data Noncmaappended;

NOTE: The data set WORK.NONCMAAPPENDED has 1 observations and 0 variables.  NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

2    proc means data=Noncmaappended maxdec=3;  
3    run;

NOTE: No variables in data set WORK.NONCMAAPPENDED.  NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 secon
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
1    data Noncmaappended;
```

is the problem.  That's deleting your dataset and re-creating a 1 row, 0 variable dataset.  Remove that line and rerun the prior step (that the log showed had lots of variables and observations) and you should be good.